# Azure Ad B2C - Output Claims do not return email address as a single value, but an array instead

Tags: security, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

For some reason Azure B2C returns an email_addressess claim instead of the standard open id policy spec claim for email. "email" or "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress". Why is this? It should return this along with an array of alternate or all emails. When trying to integrate with existing applications expecting that claim, they do not work.

If I want to add "email" as an output claim, do I need to upload a custom policy? This is a painful process.

Is there a way to achieve editing the ReplyingParty section of an existing policy without having to build custom policies from scratch? This process requires you to download the entire policy which is 5 sub sections, then break them up, edit them, then re-upload. There has to be a way to add one additional output claim without doing all of this.

Comment: I've the exact same question. Since it's 2 months ago you posted this; did you already found a way to return the email claim in user flows?

Comment: Yes, see below.

Comment: Ok, but if I understand correctly this is by using custom policies? It not possible when user user flows?

Comment: Correct. Out of the box AzureB2C does not support the email claim, only the array. MSFT did not elaborate why. But I was able to get it working doing the steps below.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working with help from MSFT :

Follow the steps in #1

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#get-the-starter-pack
2. Use one of the starter packs as it suggests : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack
3. Then modify the starter pack you use to add:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email"/>
```

to the Technical Profile in the `SignUpOrSignin.xml` file. You will then get the proper claim back as expected.